# How do I start creating these small Animations?

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects, resource-recommendations

I am a UI-UX Designer working for web and mobile apps since last 2 years. Now I am planning to expand my skills and want to learn basics of Animations (e.g Compositing a Mobile App into a Cell Phone) , GIF Animations etc.

https://www.behance.net/gallery/42033301/Paulig-Cafemoji

I know I need to learn Adobe After Effects but which path, books, tutorials should I start watching to get a good grip of this area?

Answer (score 2):

In the age of youtube, and After Effects, the two have met their ideal partners.

Start here, 20 minute introduction to After Effects, or similar:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6tR3fpv4Aco

Then to specific task masters, like Mikey:

https://www.youtube.com/user/LongLiveMikey/videos

and Evan:

https://www.youtube.com/user/ECAbrams/videos

But don't stop here if these people don't appeal. There's others along the same lines with completely different personalities.

AE is a wide program, lots of features and effects. So it just takes time to see and try a lot of them. It's not a deep and wide app like Maya and 3ds Max, so unfortunately it never becomes intuitive like they do.